# Nested attributes of validation form field value cleared

Tags: attributes, nested, nested-attributes, formfield

I am having form of user.Where user table has username and email address and another table of user profile which has user_id,location etc..
i am using the form below

I have done the vaildation for user email_Addreess uniqueness.if validation happens then i render to the same page.

My problem was if validation happen and render to same page the values in the fields of city,locations value field gets cleared.but values remains in other fields.Pls re me soon

```
<%= form_for @user_usr, :url => { :action => "provider_submit" } do |f| %>
<%=params.inspect%>
  <% @user_usr.build_user_profile_pfl%>
  <% if @user_usr.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <ul>
        <% @user_usr.errors.each_with_index do |msg, i| %>
          <!--for valdiation -->
          <li><%= msg[1] %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  username<%= f.text_field :username_usr,:id=>"p_name",:name=>"p_name", :class=>"lt textbox_provider",:maxlength => 50,:style=>"outline: none;",:onclick =>"focusChangeBorderColor('p_name');",:onblur=>"blurChangeBorderColor('p_name')",:onchange=>"removeunwantedSpace(this.value)", :tabindex => '1'%>
  email<%= f.text_field :email_usr,:id=>"p_email",:name=>"p_email", :class=>"lt textbox_provider",:maxlength => 50,:style=>"outline: none;",:onclick =>"focusChangeBorderColor('p_email');",:onblur=>"blurChangeBorderColor('p_email')",:onchange=>"removeunwantedSpace(this.value)", :tabindex => '2'%>


  <%= f.fields_for :user_profile_pfl do |builder| %>
    City <%= builder.text_field :city,:id=>"b_name",:name=>"b_name", :class=>"lt textbox_provider",:maxlength => 50,:style=>"outline: none;",:onclick =>"focusChangeBorderColor('b_name');",:onblur=>"blurChangeBorderColor('b_name')",:onchange=>"removeunwantedSpace(this.value)", :tabindex => '2'%>
  <%end%>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<%end%>
```

Comment: add code to let us understand your code

Comment: i have added the form..due want anything